# React Number Format and Styled Components - props getting passed to the DOM

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-number-format

I have an `Input` component created with Styled Components:

```
const Input = styled.input`
  ${({ boxShadow, theme }) => css`
    ...
    box-shadow: ${boxShadow};
  `}
`;
```

I am using it as a standalone component:

```
<Input placeholder="Regular input" boxShadow="..." />
```

and together with the React Number Format component for styling:

```
<Input as={NumberFormat} placeholder="Number input" boxShadow="..." />
```

Everything works OK, except that when used in conjunction with React Number Format any custom properties my `Input` component has are passed to the DOM and React doesn't like it:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `boxShadow` prop on a DOM element.

Any way to prevent React Number Format from passing custom properties I have down to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

depends on the version you are using, but

> If you want to prevent props meant to be consumed by styled components
> from being passed to the underlying React node or rendered to the DOM
> element, you can prefix the prop name with a dollar sign ($), turning
> it into a transient prop.

https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props

if you want more granular filtering you can use [shouldForwardProps()](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#shouldforwardprop)

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it gave me a different error of a similar type. Turned out React Number Format has a similar prop called `customInput` so the solution I found is doing it this way `<NumberFormat customInput={Input} ... />` instead.